# How to connect to the Internet with Linux open SUSE via DSL?

Tags: open-source, internet-connection, suse

I use open SUSE 11.3 and want to connect to the Internet but I can't configure out how to do it, any help is previously appreciated.

Comment: I hope you mean 11.3

Comment: You might want to be more specific.  What DSL provider and what hardware, for starters.  What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chris is very correct. there is little point doing it yourself in linux especially if you have to ask (sorry if I sound rude).

However, for the matter, run yast -> network service -> DSL

or you need to download roaring-penguin PPPoE client:

http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/pppoe

Compile it, then run adsl-setup, adsl-start (to connect) and adsl-stop (to disconnect).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to connect your computer to a router, and hook up the router to the DSL modem.  You can either configure your computer to use DHCP, or hard-code an IP address.

I do remember in the "bad old days" when you had to run software on your desktop to talk to the modem, but I'm pretty those days are gone.